# Echo without a newline character results a syntax error

Tags: bash

I am writing a shell script and I would like to have this code

```
echo $(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 3600 | bc
```

without the newline character at the end.
I wanted to write it using echo -n, but this code

```
echo -n $(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 3600 | bc
```

results a syntax error:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Can you help me with this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 3600 | bc | tr -d "\n"`

Alternatives:

`echo -n $(($(cut -d . -f 1 /proc/uptime)/3600))`

`mapfile A </proc/uptime; echo -n $((${A%%.*}/3600))`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `echo -n`:

```
echo -n $(echo $(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 3600 | bc)
```

In general, if `foo` produces a line of output, you can print the same output without a newline using `echo -n $(foo)`, even if `foo` is complicated.

A more straightforward solution using pure `awk` (since `awk` does arithmetic *and* output formatting, there's not  much point in using both `awk` and `bc`):

```
awk '{printf("%d", $1 / 3600)}' /proc/uptime
```